# How can I store data on DynamoDB to allow keywords queries?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a set of data I want to store about restaurants that contains keywords. (Let's say a list of 50 keywords per item.)

How should I architect the database so I can make queries on keywords?

Comment: What's stopping you? This is way too vague. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy Please show me where I have YELL ?

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag I was talking about an all-uppercase comment that is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing the wrong tool for the job. Dynamodb is not optimized for search and that's basically what you want to do. Queries are based on PK that define server location.
You could possibly create a GSI for each keyword so you can query based on those. But don't do that. It's hacky, not scalable and you'd pay for storage 50x more.

The usual solution for such case is replication of data, probably best to ElasticSearch. DynamoDB stays as your main datastore but the data is replicated do ElasticSearch that you can use to search over keywords.

Replication is easiest achieved using Lambda function with DynamoDB streams